# Is deleting a file under MPL 1.1 is a license violation?

Tags: gpl, lgpl, mpl

I have an open source code repository under MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1.
My question: is deleting a file is a license violation ?

Comment: Are you going to delete the "LICENSE" or "NOTICE" file? Then probably no. See [Remove BSD LICENSE file while importing code into GPL project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/can-i-remove-files-and-folders-in-a-php-package-without-violating-its-license)

Comment: For removing other files see [can I remove files and folders in a PHP package without violating its license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/can-i-remove-files-and-folders-in-a-php-package-without-violating-its-license)